# Covariant derivative of metric determinant with torsion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation

I have some troubles taking the covariant derivative of the metric determinant with torsion. Let's suppose that we take a metric such that $\nabla_\mu g_{\nu\rho}=0$. My reasoning is the following.

Let's start from the well known formula
$$
\ln(\det g) = \text{tr}(\ln g)
$$
taking the derivative we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{\det g}\partial_\rho \det g = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu} \quad \longrightarrow \quad \partial_\rho \sqrt{\det g} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\det g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu} 
$$
writing the Christoffel symbols as $\Gamma(e)$ we notice that
$$
\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\nu(e) = \frac{1}{2}g^{ab}\partial_\mu g_{ab}
$$
therefore
$$
\partial_\rho \sqrt{\det g} = \sqrt{\det g}\Gamma_{\rho\nu}^{\nu}(e) \quad \longrightarrow \quad \partial_\rho \sqrt{\det g} - \Gamma_{\rho\nu}^{\nu}(e)\sqrt{\det g} = 0
$$
we got this equation for the volume form, and from this we get
$$
\nabla_\rho \sqrt{\det g} = 0
$$

On the other hand I can take ($\Gamma$ is the full connection with torsion)
$$
\nabla_\mu g_{\nu\rho} = 0 \quad \longrightarrow \quad \partial_\mu g_{\nu\rho} = \Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\gamma g_{\gamma\rho} + \Gamma_{\mu\rho}^\gamma g_{\nu\gamma}
$$
from before we get
$$
\partial_\rho \sqrt{\det g} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\det g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\det g}g^{\mu\nu}(\Gamma_{\rho\mu}^\gamma g_{\gamma\nu} + \Gamma_{\rho\nu}^\gamma g_{\mu\gamma}) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\det g}(\Gamma_{\rho\mu}^\mu + \Gamma_{\rho\nu}^\nu ) = \sqrt{\det g}\Gamma_{\rho\mu}^\mu
$$
therefore
$$
\partial_\rho \sqrt{\det g} - \Gamma_{\rho\nu}^{\nu}\sqrt{\det g} = 0
$$
I think that this last one should be the correct equation, so that
$$
\nabla_\rho \sqrt{\det g} = 0
$$
but why?

Comment: I might have found out why but I am not entirely sure, I think both relations are true and we can go from one to other because $\Gamma_{\rho\mu}^\mu = \Gamma_{\rho\mu}^\mu (e) - K_{\rho\mu}{}^\mu$ but $K$ is antisymmetric in the last two entries, therefore it is 0.